# multiple JSON files that I would like to parse, edit, and merge into one object,

Tags: php, json

Hi everyone in stackexhange

i needed multiple .json file decode from folder

I have multiple JSON files that I would like to parse, edit, and merge into one object, which will ultimately get re-encoded and output as a single JSON.

Her my code of one .json file decode

```
<?php 
    if ( file_exists( BASE . '/contents/cache/recent-file.json' ) ) {
        $recent_file = json_decode( file_get_contents( BASE . '/contents/cache/recent-file.json' ), true );
        if ( $recent_file ) {
?>

    <div class="items-list">
            <?php 
                foreach( array_reverse($recent_file) as $key => $apps ) {
                    get_template( 'templates/app-item', $apps );                    


            ?>
        </div>      
<?php } } ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to:

1. Get the list of all the JSON files
2. Get the contents of each file
3. Add the contents of those files to a PHP array
4. Output as a new JSON object

My method would be:

```
//Get all the JSON files
$files = glob("/path/to/folder/*.json");

//Create an empty new array
$newDataArray = [];

//Get the contents of each file
foreach($files as $file){
    $thisData = file_get_contents($file);

    //Decode the json
    $thisDataArray = json_decode($thisData);

    //Add $thisData to the new array
    $newDataArray[] = $thisDataArray;
}

//Encode the array to JSON
$newDataJSON = json_encode($newDataArray);
```

Now you can do what you wish with the `$newDataJSON` object, for example save it to a new `.json` file:

```
file_put_contents("/path/to/file.json",$newDataJSON);
```

Comment: how to get each data    $newDataJSON as $key => $app

Comment: @SunnyKumar That isn't clear to me. What is the `$key` and what is `$app`?

Comment: or how to save total detail.json file after newDataJSON

Comment: multiple JSON files to one file with one json file

Comment: I've added this to my answer. Please use Google - it's your friend! [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: thanks bro.. give me total script for saving .json file

Comment: any script which auto  delete  or replace  my word  : {"results": .. this world has detete in .json